# Editing a pages HTML form, within a form?

Tags: php, html, mysql

For a website I'm currently building, I decided to let admin log in, and edit all of the source within each pages main content div. I'm using PHP and SQL to retrieve the source of the desired page (based on url). If a certain login session variable is set, and $_REQUEST["edit_page"] == true, the source of the content div is placed within a textarea, within a form.

This system really doesn't work if I try to add a form to the source. Anything outside of the pages source's form, displays as it would if the page wasnt being edited.

Is there any way around this?

EDIT:
Here's an example.

```
<form action="" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="edit_text" value="true"><input type="hidden" name="text_id" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="data_sent" value="true"><textarea name="new_text">

// SOURCE GOES HERE, LETS YOU EDIT IT, THEN SUBMIT IT, TO OVERWRITE THE CURRENT DATA STORED FOR THIS PAGE IN THE DATABASE

</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

This doesn't work if the source includes a form. It messes with the existing form, in which you are editing the source.

EDIT:

Basically, how do I display HTML source within a textarea, without it acting like HTML source?

Worked out you can use htmlspecialchars() in PHP to solve this. Problem solved.

Comment: show some code and the error.

Comment: It is not realy clear what`s your problem maybe you can setup a http://jsfiddle.net/ to show the error with an example. You can also show a image of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You use htmlspecialchars() PHP function to display html source within textareas.

http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10208990-display-html-source-in-text-area&p=10218525#post10218525

Comment: It is one option to do it when you are trying to make a easy html source editor maybe you could implement a `WYSIWYG` editor like this one: http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/

Comment: I like this idea :) but I think i'd prefer to program an editor by myself, using Javascript. Sounds like fun practice.